# Is it possible to run a function without giving it an object?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm wondering if there are any functions, that run a function.

For example if the simplest function I could write is something like:

```
function(){
  print("hello world")
}
```

However as far as I know the only way to "run" this function is to run something like:

```
my_fun <- function(){
  print("hello world")
}

my_fun()
```

Is there a way to achieve this result without giving the function an object? Intuitively I think this is not too different than what `%>%` does, but I'm having trouble thinking about how to do this. Is there a function that I could pipe into to run this function without giving it it's own object?

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you mean by "without giving the function an object". On its face, that would seem to mean "without passing any arguments", which you've clearly done in your example. Maybe better terminology would be that you want to **call** a function without doing....something? It's the something part that we still don't know much about.

Comment: You can call `(function(){print("hello world")})()`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do can **IIFE** (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression). It´s a quite popular pattern in JS.

```
(function() {print("hello world")})()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're just asking if you can run a function without explicitly naming it.  Sure.

```
(function(){
  print("hello world")
})()
```

Wrap the anonymous function in parens and then 'call' it with a pair of parens as well.

```
> (function(){
+   print("hello world")
+ })()
[1] "hello world"
```